# Browsing with IE causes 'Error 80004004' in SignIn widget

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, movabletype

I am using Movable Type 4.23 and have been testing my site on a PC and discovered that Internet Explorer is unable to view my site due to a conflict in the javascript of the signin widget (initially I thought it was in the mt.js file).

I receive this error: `Error 80004004` as well as in the Javascript itself:

> "Element is not an object"
>
> (or object is not an element?)

```
function mtUpdateSignInWidget(u) {
    var el = document.getElementById('signin-widget-content');
```

If I put in `id` where `sign-widget-content` goes, it will say it is not an object.

All other browsers work perfectly (Firefox, safari and opera on my mac and Firefox on PC). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, please include a link to the test page in the question. The 'fault' will in some way relate to the JS and the HTML. Both need to be seen for the cause to be identified.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities for this error.

1) There is no element with the ID you've entered. Check to make sure the ID is exactly right, including correct upper and lower case letter.

2) The element DOES exist, but the JavaScript is running BEFORE it has been rendered in your document. Calls to an element should always occur AFTER they appear on the page.